# Clone a Git repository with another name

Tags: git, git-clone

How can I clone a repository with name `myproject`?

The server directory is named with a unique code like `584ffceed.git` using smart `https`. How do I set permissions that ask for a username and password and give rights to push or pull?

Comment: `git clone` -> https://git-scm.com/docs/git-clone

Answer (score 27):

To clone into `myproject` just do `git clone .../584ffceed.git myproject`.

Regarding your other question, it is not really clear what you are asking. Please rephrase the question to make it clear.

Comment: How do i make git ask for username and password for my http://site.tk and authenticate and then let it clone or push

Comment: can i do it using php?

Comment: You said you use Smart HTTP like desribed here: https://git-scm.com/book/be/v2/Git-on-the-Server-Smart-HTTP ? This page also describes how to add authentication.

Comment: any idea how to do it with nginx?

Comment: Never used that

Comment: what should be the exact apache2 conf for this?

Comment: Follow the link I gave you, it shows an example. Other than that, follow Apache documentation, there are a gazillion ways to set up authentication with Apache, depending on actual needs.

Answer (score 9):

Clone the repository in this manner:

```
git clone clone_url.git project_name
```

Answer (score 8):

From `man git-clone`:

```
   git clone [--template=<template_directory>]
             [-l] [-s] [--no-hardlinks] [-q] [-n] [--bare] [--mirror]
             [-o <name>] [-b <name>] [-u <upload-pack>] [--reference <repository>]
             [--dissociate] [--separate-git-dir <git dir>]
             [--depth <depth>] [--[no-]single-branch]
             [--recursive | --recurse-submodules] [--[no-]shallow-submodules]
             [--jobs <n>] [--] <repository> [<directory>]

<directory>
           The name of a new directory to clone into.
           The "humanish" part of the source repository is used if no directory is explicitly given (repo for /path/to/repo.git and foo for
           host.xz:foo/.git).
           Cloning into an existing directory is only allowed if the directory is empty.
```

It's the argument <directory> placed directly after the repository URI.

Comment: How do i make git ask for username and password for my http://site.tk and authenticate and then let it clone or push, that is allowing only a particular user to push to a particular repo

Comment: and to do it in nginx

Comment: @shreyanshgoel You need to ask a new question in a new post for that and we'll surely help you

Comment: please visit https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42163833/ask-username-and-password-for-git-push-nginx

Comment: @shreyanshgoel you should accept one of the answers if your problem related to `git clone` was solved